# Getting the below error in Playwright when trying to upload a file : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: typescript, file-upload, filepath, playwright

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C9jQ.png)I just started using playwright(using typescript), so I am very new to it. I am having a test script where I need to upload a single file. The element type is non-input HTML so I am choosing Filechooser function for the upload. I have placed the pdf file which needs to be uploaded under the attachments subfolder section. Attaching the image here as well and attaching the code snippet too. As per the screenshot, I am making changes to the WaterTDLApp.Spec.ts which is under tests folder. Tests and attachments folders are under src folder.

Full Error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\attachments\TDL\relevantfile-sample.pdf'

```js
const filepath = '../../attachments/TDL/relevantfile-sample.pdf';
  
    const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
      // It is important to call waitForEvent before click to set up waiting.
      page.waitForEvent('filechooser'),
      // Opens the file chooser.
      page.locator("(//*[@class='ant-upload-drag-container'])[1]").click(),
    ]);

    await  fileChooser.setFiles(filepath)
```

Could anyone please help me here. Let me know if any other details are needed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAV0w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are running the tests from `C:\OneStop 2.0 Automation\E2E`, then you have to change the file path to `src/attachments/TDL/relevantfile-sample.pdf`. This should work.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after updating the above file path.

Comment: Full error is this : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\attachments\TDL\relevantfile-sample.pdf'

Comment: Can you tell me the absolute path of your test file and your sample pdf ?

Comment: Sample pdf - C:\OneStop 2.0 Automation\E2E\src\attachments\TDL\relevantfile-sample.pdf. Test file - C:\OneStop 2.0 Automation\E2E\src\tests\water-tdl-app\WaterTDLApp.spec.ts

Comment: How about you try this `../../../src/attachments/TDL/relevantfile-sample.pdf` ?

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\src\attachments\TDL\relevantfile-sample.pdf'

Comment: The problem here is Playwright is looking for the file in reference from where the test is run from. So are you running the test execute command from E2E folder level ? Or, send me the terminal screenshot of how you are executing the test.

Comment: I have added the image in the post. Are you able to see it? Also see the path in terminal below:- PS C:\OneStop 2.0 Automation\E2E> npx playwright test --headed

Comment: Your path will be then from E2E - `src/attachments/TDL/relevantfile-sample.pdf`.

Comment: So shall I update the filepath to above you are saying?

Comment: Just use this in your test `const filepath = 'src/attachments/TDL/relevantfile-sample.pdf';`

Comment: Thank you so much. It finally worked. Really appreciate your efforts in helping me.